# Are there jQuery like selectors for XML parsing?

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I need to parse xml and main element names varies and I only need few details form XML, what is very complicated. Are there any way to parse XML with jQuery like seletors?

Comment: jQuery makes things like this too easy - then you dread going back to anything else. That said, I don't know Java so I'm of no use to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this with using HTML parser jsoup (http://jsoup.org/).

Comment: When I do : `Elements xmlBlocs = doc.select("bloc");` then `xmlBlocs.get(0).select("place")`, I'm getting **place** from other __blocs__ elements... Why ?

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for XQuery.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XQuery